# Only Lower Half Of The Border Is Shown

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

CSS

```
.socialmedia 
{
    border: solid 10px transparent;
}

.socialmedia.hover 
{ 
    border-color: WHITE; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mediashelter" >
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="fbid" class="socialmedia" target="_blank">
<img src="lol.jpg"></a>  
</div>
```

Source

http://truestar.sdf.org/check/lol.html

How can I make the entire border to appear?  At the moment I just see the lower part of the border

Comment: the element isn't keeping to the size of the image, for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` as follows:

```
.socialmedia 
{
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    display:inline-block;
}
```